# assigning a role to a user programatically

Tags: users

I have been looking around for how to assign a role to a user programatically and there is some discussion. Basing my code a little off of https://drupal.org/node/28379, will this work?

```
    global $user;
    $myuser = user_load($user->uid); 
    $myuser->$role[4] = 'Member';
    user_save($myuser);
```

where I already know that the Member role is stored at key 4 (I did a print_r on user who is assigned that role and I see

```
 [roles] => Array ( [2] => authenticated user [4] => Member )
```

Comment: _will this work?_ What happens when you try it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically assign user role](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/49533/programmatically-assign-user-role). Also connected [Assign all users a new Role in Drupal 7](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/29832/16495).

Comment: It did not seem to work, I checked to assigned roles and it wasn't set

Comment: I didn't think this was duplicate, because I am trying to do this from inside hook_user_login, which the other examples are not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$uid = 123;// User ID of user that you want to add role to.
$role_name = 'Role to add'; // The name of the role to add.
if ($role = user_role_load_by_name($role_name)) {
  user_multiple_role_edit(array($uid), 'add_role', $role->rid);
}
```

Is how you should do it in Drupal 7. See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_multiple_role_edit/7

Answer (score 0):

load the user by uid and send the  user object to this function and the role name this function will add role to the user

```
   // Add new role to existing roles.
    function add_role_to_user($account, $role){
      // Add new role to existing roles.
        $role_name = $role;
        if (isset($account->uid) && $account->uid > 0) {
          $userId = $account->uid;
          $newaccount = $new_role = array();
            // If the user doesn't already have the role, add the role to that user.
            $key = array_search($role_name, $account -> roles);
            if ($key === FALSE) {
              // Get the rid from the roles table.
              $roles = user_roles(TRUE);
              $rid = array_search($role_name, $roles);
              if(is_numeric($rid)) {
                $new_role[$rid] = $role_name;
                $newaccount['roles'] = $account -> roles + $new_role;

              }
            }

            user_save($account, $newaccount);
        }

    }
```

add the above function and add this code to add role to user

```
$user = user_load(1);
add_role_to_user($user,"Role name");
```

Here added sample uid add your own uid and pass will add role to the user if you want to update multiple use loop in the two line code will solve your problem