# Display block on first login only

Tags: users, blocks

I want to display a block on first login only and never after that, is there any module or something possible for that?
I have a block which is visible always on the first page, but what i need is to show the block only once and never ever after. That block contains a link to start a javascript on page for the tour(Joyride Module). The problem is, If i select "Play tour once", It plays the tour once for every session and as soon as user comes after some time, I will restart the tour. I want the tour to start only once after login. I have decided to do it by showing the link to manually start the tour in a block and that block would be visible only after first login. So, is it possible?

Comment: Will the block disappear if you refresh the page? I imagine this can be confusing for users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[First Login Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/first_login) will do the job for you , this is some description about this module from its page :

> A simple utility module which enables the use of "first logins". With this module the site admin can enable content or do things that appear only on the first login for users by using modules like Context or Views. Couple useful functions are included for use in custom modules.

Comment: Not really updated but might do the job.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a hidden field on the user profile, like a flag, default value as 0, in a custom module you load the block and then change the value of the field.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the
[user alert](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_alert) module

Here is description how to use this module:

> Enable User Alerts Set the appropriate permissions for selected roles
>   Set the User Alert block in the appropriate region of your theme.
>   Create a user alert node.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to check if it is the first time user has logged in. You can create and assign a custom role with the name of `logged_in` for any user who logs in. the level of permissions is not important for this role.

Now if any user logs in and he/she has this role, it means it is not the first time he/she visits your site otherwise it is the first time and you must [load the block programmatically](http://www.whenwhowhere.com/tech-blog/outputting-block-programmatically-drupal-7) and [assign the role to it programmatically](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/87522/assigning-a-role-to-a-user-programatically). You can implement this in `hook_user_login` as follow:

```
function THEME_user_login(&$edit, $account) {
     if (!in_array('logged_in', $account->roles)) {
     // assign the role to the user and load the block programmatically , it is her/his first login 

            $uid = $account->uid;// User ID of user that logs in
            $role_name = 'logged_in'; // The name of the role to add.
            if ($role = user_role_load_by_name($role_name)) {
             user_multiple_role_edit(array($uid), 'add_role', $role->rid);
            }
            $block = module_invoke('module_name', 'block_view', 'block_id');
            print render ($block); 
       }
}
```

**Don't forget not to load (or assign the block) on (to) any region by default**